# Can I really not use table markup to get two elements to have equal height?

Tags: html, css, tablelayout

OK, so I know using `table` for layout is deeply unfashionable. But I need to do a a layout with two side-by-side elements, one with a usual height that can increase if it has taller contents, and the other containing an image. If the first one grows taller, I want the one with the image to grow to match its height.

This is something I can easily achieve with good old `table`. How can I do it with divs?

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```css
.body {
  width: 748px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
.breaker {
  margin: 20px 0;
  outline: 1px solid purple;
}
.poll {
  background: pink;
  width: 248px;
  height: 250px;
}
div.poll {
  float: left;
}
.story {
  float: right;
  width: 500px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">

  <table class="breaker">
    <tr>
      <!-- This will have a variable height depending on content -->
      <td class="poll"></td>
      <!-- The height of this should match the height of .poll -->
      <td style="width:500px;background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-600-200-1.jpg);background-size:cover;">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <div class="breaker">
    <!-- This will have a variable height depending on content -->
    <div class="poll"></div>
    <!-- The height of this should match the height of .poll -->
    <div class="story" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-600-200-1.jpg)">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Equal height is one of native features of <table> layout, or CSS table layout, see this simplified demo - http://jsfiddle.net/LLy1sLhq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `display: table-cell` to both and remove `float`.

```
div.poll {
    display: table-cell;
    /* other styles */
}

.story {
    display:table-cell;
    /* other styles */
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/j8gxLg2z/)

Comment: @AndFinally Thanks FYI, you can completely replace table elements with css display property values like `table`, `table-column`, `table-row`, `table-cell`. it will better if you check MDN for brief and clear information.

Answer (score -1):

This is a jQuery answer, but I actually wrote this yesterday so I know it works:

```
function setToTargetHeight(obj1, obj2){

    var targetHeight = $(obj1).innerHeight();

    $(obj2).css('height', targetHeight);

}
```

So in use it would be like this:

```
setToTargetHeight('#theTextDiv','#theImageDiv');
```

This is awkwardly named so if anyone has any suggestions on how to name this function that would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks plushy, I think a CSS solution is better for my particular case, but good to throw this into the mix.